# Windows Search Service Fails to Start

Tags: windows-vista, windows-search

My Windows Search service will not run on my Windows Vista PC.

When I try to start it, I get the error:

> **Error 3: The system cannot find the path specified.**
>
> The file **C:\Windows\system32\SearchIndexer.exe** does exist.

I have deleted all directories under **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search**

Any ideas?

Comment: There are high possibilities of your PC to be infected by a virus

Comment: "I have deleted all firectories under C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search"
I think you have found your problem.

Comment: @Mr-Right - there is no virus. @Moab - that is a suggested fix, it forces the index service to re-index everything, although it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everything mentioned here: http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/85803-index-windows-search-service.html but it didn’t work.

So I ended up installing [Windows Search 4](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/choose/windowssearch4.mspx) and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try a scan for broken system files.

1. Click **Start**
2. Click **Run**
3. Type **`sfc /scannow`** and click **OK**

If there are any corrupt files, including the `SearchIndexer.exe` file - they will automatically be replaced with the good copy.  You might need to pop in your Vista installation CD when prompted, if it does find any problems.

Failing this, a simple [**System Restore**](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-windows-vista-system-restore/) back to when it was all working okay should do the trick.